# Improve visjs performance

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to display roughly around 59k points on a 3d [visjs](http://visjs.org/graph3d_examples.html) graph. I have them displaying, but the performance it really really bad. You can hardly do anything it's so slow.

Is there any way I can improve the performance of the graph, or even just generally for canvas?

Comment: From visjs.org: *Graph3d uses HTML canvas to render graphs,* ***and can render up to a few thousands of data points smoothly***. what **is** the question?

Comment: @Amit I'm trying to render about 59k points, and the performance is not good at all. So the question is asking if there is a way to improve the bad performance I'm getting with the tons of data

Comment: Yes that's all very clear, but it is also very clear from the official documentation that this library is not designed for that kind of data, so what is the question? Are you asking if the documentation is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's typical `O(N)` problem so you need to come up with other solutions.

For example: instead of drawing each star of the Universe you can just draw star clusters as bold dots. Or something like that.

That will reduce amount of work by orders of magnitude.

Comment: One problem with doing it that way is that my users need to be able to see all the actual data, also the shape of the data isn't in a way that would be easily or conveniently converted to be displayed in groups like that

Comment: @KeithM: IMHO, c-smile's answer is right on point. Asking users to differentiate 59K individual data points will overwhelm them. With 59K points, you'll need take the extra step of grouping &/or aggregating your data even if it is initially inconveniently shaped. That way you can give your users a way to start with grouped sets of your data & then "drill-down" on the set they are interested in.  I haven't used visjs, but it looks like they have a heat map which is a good way of presenting large quantities of aggregated data.